# Eyeball gloss not visible behind another glass object

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, glass

I have these objects with glasslike materials

I used refraction and glossy shaders because I dont like the double relfection I get with a glass shader.

But even with a glass shader my eye glass shader is not visible behind it.

[image]`

[image]

This is my reference:
Clear reflections, clear see through glass

[image]

Any tips, trick or advice?

Comment: Its already on 12 and doubling it doesnt change anything. any other options?

Comment: try doing the shaders with Shadow Ray handling only. You used Reflection and Camera Rays also, it could be somehow because of that and you dont need them anyway in this case, as far as I see your problem. Also look through the materials tab and search for transparent shadows, maybe that affects it.

Comment: sorry I was confusing with another problem  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I tested your setup and found your mistake. The outer ball material is more or less correct (You can omit the reflection ray handling). The problem is the inner reflection material of the eye. Just remove everything you have done with Light Paths in that material and it should work perfectly fine.

**EDIT:**
Also you should change out the Glass BSDF for a Glossy BSDF in the eye reflection. At least I found it to work better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. works as intended now :)